Can I change the order of integrating in this case?
So, let's say I have
$$
I=\int_0^\infty{F(x, \alpha, \beta)}dx
$$
Now, let's say I want to take the indefinite integral with respect to $\beta$ from $I$. Would this be correct?
$$
\int I=\int_0^\infty{(\int{F(x, \alpha, \beta})d\beta)dx}
$$
and, using the notation :$I' = \int{F(x, \alpha, \beta})d\beta = f(x,\alpha,\beta) + C_1 $if I can prove that $C_1=0$ here.
$$
\int I=\int_0^\infty{f(x,\alpha, \beta)dx+C_2}
$$

If there are no further assumptions on F this should be false since in general you cannot interchange the order of integration.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem
